# Akka starter: Maven and IntelliJ IDEA out-of-sync

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, akka, akka-cluster

After a few tutorials I wanted to build my own chat with Akka to play around a little bit. To make things more difficult, I'm also trying to pick up IntelliJ IDEA as well after a few years of Eclipse.

I've set up a simple POM to get akka-cluster, enabled auto-import and set up IDEA to support Scala (via right-click on the project and enabling Scala under "Framework support"); I've wrote a few lines of code to get things started. The weird thing is that while the code compiles and runs correctly (prints "hello, world" and quits), IDEA reports that somethings wrong with my code (errors that I'd expect to result in failing compilation).

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-chat-sim</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-cluster_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.example.tutorials.akka.chat

import akka.actor.{Props, ActorLogging, Actor, ActorSystem}

class Foo extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case s: String => {
      log.info(s)
      context.system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("foo")
  val foo = system.actorOf(Props[Foo], "foo")

  foo ! "hello, world"

}
```

IntelliJ IDEA says that the ActorSystem import is unused (although it is used) and after a few lines it says that it cannot resolve ActorSystem.apply (although somehow it does, since it compiles and runs correctly).

Furthermore, it highlights the closing brace of the receive method of Foo, telling me that `Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to expected type BoxedUnit`.

What am I missing? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, it seems the culprit was a .idea folder I created when trying to bundle all the Akka tutorials I was studying as modules of a single project.

I noticed it, deleted it and cleared IntelliJ's cache as Eric suggested in his reply. After doing so, I restarted IntelliJ and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I took your `pom.xml` and source file and followed the same steps you described. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem. The code compiles and runs fine as you also report, but IntelliJ also does not report any problems (except one inspection warning about redundant braces).

What version of IntelliJ and the Scala plugin are you running?
The more recent versions of the Scala plugin are much improved over older versions.

You could try invalidating your caches to force the indexes to be built again (File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...)

The versions I am running:

- IntelliJ      14.0.2  (Ultimate version)
- Scala Plugin  1.1.3

Also, if you are using IntelliJ 14, make sure you are *not* using any Play plugin or SBT plugin in conjunction with the Scala plugin. The most recent version of the Scala plugin includes support for Play and SBT so no other Scala-related plugin is necessary.

Even though I found no problem using Maven with your files, another suggestion might be to start with the [typesafe activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) template `akka-sample-cluster-scala` and, with the Scala plugin enabled, open it in IntelliJ as an `sbt` project. Most Scala projects use `sbt` as the build tool rather than Maven.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.
I'm on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.0.1 and Scala Plugin 1.1.3.
I thought I was going to solve the problem by invalidating the caches, but after the indexes have been rebuilt, the issue reappeared. Actually, I first got this issue with an Activator tutorial template (akka-clustering), although I did not import it as an SBT project as you described, but rather had Activator generate the IntelliJ project files so that I could open it. I'll try to regenerate the template from scratch and import it as an SBT project. Thanks again!

Comment: I've tried to regenerate the project from the template from scratch and importing it as an SBT project. Same as before, but the issues reported by IntelliJ changed. This is really puzzling. I'm trying to update to 14.0.2.

Comment: Indeed, it must be frustrating. The only thing other thing I can think of is, are you using the standard maven directory structure for your source file, i.e. src/main/scala/... ; and if all else fails, maybe there is something in your environment, maybe try it on a different machine?  Good luck in any case!

Comment: I've replied my own question. I accidently created a .idea folder in the project shared parent directory. I guess its settings most have somehow interfered with IntelliJ's proper functioning. Thanks for the cache cleanup suggestion, it came in handy after I deleted the folder.